Determining if the three-equation model is isomorphic to the three-point plane model
I'm self studying off of the textbook "Axiomatic Geometry" by John Lee. During the text, the author mentions of the following models of incidence geometry:
Three-point plane model
(1) A "point" is any of the numbers 1, 2 or 3
(2) A "line" is any of the sets {1,2}, {1,3} or {2,3}
(3) A point "lies on" a line if it is a member of the line's set
Three-equation model
(1) A "point" is any of the tuples $(1,0), (0,1)$ or $(1,1)$
(2) A "line" is any of the equations $x = 1, y = 1$ or $x + y = 1$
(3) A point $(a,b)$ "lies on" a line if $x = a, y = b$ solves the line's equation
Now, we are told to prove that these two models are isomorphic. First of all, I tried the following: $1\xrightarrow{}(1,0)$, $2\xrightarrow{}(0,1)$ and $3\xrightarrow{}(1,1)$. Similarly, the lines were mapped in the following way: {1,2}$\xrightarrow{}x = 1$, {1,3}$\xrightarrow{}y = 1$ and {2,3}$\xrightarrow{}x + y = 1$.
However, in this way, the "lies on" operation is not preserved. So how do you proceed from here? Does this mean that the two models aren't isomorphic? Or do you just proceed with trial-and-error until you find the function that works?
(P.S I'm an ultra beginner just exploring these concepts while I'm in high school)
